# Coffee script and browser cache

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, browser-cache

I'm using node.js and gulp to compile coffee. Compiled js file is linked to html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/local/restore/create.js?v=150129_666"></script>
```

**EDIT:**
`create.js` is up-to-date. But the page behavior and browser debbuger show I'm using some older version of my `create.coffee`. Can't get why, and how to get rid off. Or at least use current version of `create.coffee`. Thanks.

Comment: are you changint `v` parameter after compiling create.js? also have you tried to modify headers send by your http server with expires date

Comment: Yep, chaged v parameter- nothing. Havn't tried headers yet - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have researched this topic on SO and looks like browsers can cache files even with get parameters. the best solution in my opinion: 
 [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

**solution from the link:** 
modify js name (add current time for example) when generating your html

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/local/restore/create.1221534296.js"></script>`

and using rewrite rule request appropriate file

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]`

Comment: Thanks man, I have tried this, and it works. But the point is that my create.js file is already up-to-date. Meanwhile page behavior somehow is using older version of my create.coffee.

Comment: have you experienced same in other browsers that your default? looks like browser related bug

Comment: Figured out it was a code error caused that odd behavior. Silly me.